# SQLAlchemy CASE Function Issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have been trying a lot to understand the issue with my code, but I keep struggling with a the CASE function. I can't see any typo, so any advice would be really appreciated.

I want to do the following:

```
jan_case = case([
    (and_(logweb_cold.c.FECHA >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00', logweb_cold.c.FECHA < '2023-02-01 00:00:00'), 1)
], else_=0)

feb_case = case([
    (and_(logweb_cold.c.FECHA >= '2023-02-01 00:00:00', logweb_cold.c.FECHA < '2023-03-01 00:00:00'), 1)
], else_=0)

# Define the query
query = select(
    logweb_cold.c.id,
    func.sum(jan_case).label('JanOccurrences'),
    func.sum(feb_case).label('FebOccurrences')
).where(
    and_(
        logweb_cold.c.CODERR == 'OK',
        logweb_cold.c.CODTRAN == 'xd',
        logweb_cold.c.id.in_([1, 2, 3])
    )
).group_by(
    logweb_cold.c.id
).order_by(
    logweb_cold.c.id
)
```

The issue seems to start on the Jan_case

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: @snakecharmerb ArgumentError: the "whens" argument to case(), when referring to a sequence of items, is now passed as a series of positional elements, rather than as a list.

Comment: The linked duplicate should explain it, but basically remove the square brackets (`[ ]`)  from the case definitions.